# How to close python window from script

Tags: python, windows

I am running a script in `python`, which interacts via `WebSockets` to an `HTML` page. When I close the `HTML` window, i send a command to python to finish all the processing. However, after that I would want it to close the window. I already tried `sys.exit(0)` but it only raises an error and stays open.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Please explain more. Which window do you want to close after the browser window is closed? What is the error that you see?

Comment: I am running the python.exe with some script. I want to close the python.exe window without doing it manually. Just like the window.close() function in JavaScript

Comment: `python.exe` is a console program, so it doesn't create a window itself. If you run a `.py` file in Windows, a console will be opened for the program and it will be closed when the program finishes.

Comment: Rather than running python.exe, then running the python script from it, try just double-clicking the script. Its window should close when it's finished. If double-clicking the script doesn't work, try right-clicking on it, selecting "Open With", then picking python.exe from the submenu (or, if it not listed, selecting "Chose Program..." and then selecting it).

Comment: I figure out the problem...i was not killing one thread i had in my program. Now everything is working fine. Thanks a lot